# Constructor C++ and pointer to function parameter

Tags: c++, function, c++11, pointers, constructor

I have some doubt about how to define a construct in c++11 that has as parameter a pointer to a function.I've created the class Payoff that manages the payoff of different types of options given a strike and a spot price. I've also defined three functions for several types of strikes, with the same structure (parameters and return type) and a pointer to fucntion with the purpose to manage these similar function. Here the header:

```
#ifndef PAYOFFb_H
#define PAYOFFb_H
#include <MinMax.h>
class PayOff
{
public:
    typedef double (*pf)(const double& Strike, const double& Spot); 
    double Call(const double& Strike, const double& Spot){ return max(Spot - Strike, 0.0); };
    double Put(const double& Strike, const double& Spot){ return max(Strike - Spot, 0.0); };
    double Digital(const double& Strike, const double& Spot){ return Spot > Strike ? 1 : 0; };
    PayOff(double Strike_, pf TheOptionsType_) : Strike(Strike_), TheOptionsType(TheOptionsType_){};
    double operator()(double Spot) const;
private:
    double Strike;
    pf TheOptionsType;
};
#endif
```

and the body:

```
#include "Payoff1b.h"
#include <MinMax.h>
double PayOff::operator()(double spot) const
{
    return (*TheOptionsType)(Strike, spot);
};
```

Using the following main code:

```
int main()
{ 
double Strike;
cout << "\nEnter strike\n";
cin >> Strike;
PayOff callPayOff(Strike, PayOff::Call);
PayOff putPayOff(Strike, PayOff::Put);
PayOff digitalPayOff(Strike, PayOff::Digital);
return 0;
}
```

I get this error for the constructor:

```
[...] error C2664: 'PayOff::PayOff(const PayOff &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'const PayOff &'
```

I kindly ask if someone can explain me what doesn't work

Comment: That's not the relevant error message.  Try posting all of them.

Comment: It would help if you showed relevant error messages ratherthan one corresponding to code you haven't shown.   The pointer that the constructor accepts and stores is a non-member function.   The functions being supplied are member functions.   They are different things, hence the error when the compiler tries to convert a "pointer to a member function" to a "pointer to a non-member function".

Comment: Where do you use c++11 here? You need to make functions Call/Put/Digital static, so you will be able to put them as argument of constructor

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you are trying to use member function pointer or regular function pointer.

It looks like 2nd case, for that you need your `Call`, `Put`, `Digital` to be static:

```
class PayOff
{
public:
    typedef double(*pf)(const double& Strike, const double& Spot);
    static double Call(const double& Strike, const double& Spot)
    {
        return max(Spot - Strike, 0.0);
    };
    static double Put(const double& Strike, const double& Spot)
    {
        return max(Strike - Spot, 0.0);
    };
    static double Digital(const double& Strike, const double& Spot)
    {
        return Spot > Strike ? 1 : 0;
    };
    PayOff(double Strike_, pf TheOptionsType_) : Strike(Strike_), TheOptionsType(TheOptionsType_) {};
    double operator()(double Spot) const;
private:
    double Strike;
    pf TheOptionsType;
};
```

Comment: I was not aware that the compiler needed the static keyword in this case. Anyway, I was looking for a regular function pointer and now the code is working. Thank you very much, Pavel

Comment: @aforgio Glad it helped. don't forget to accept answer